# Migration from Java 8 to Java 17-XML data passed in requestBody from postman received as NULL in Controller JDK 17, Spring 3.0.5

Tags: xml-parsing, jaxb, spring-webflux, jackson-databind, java-17

`Migration from Java 8 to Java 17, Spring 3.0.5 facing issue.
When I send XML data from postman, getting Null in Controller, not the actual value passed.
I am using JDK 17 + Spring Version - 3.0.5.
Header Content-Type - application/xml.
**io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody**;

**Pojo**

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull; 
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="HEADERMLW")
public class Headmlw implements Serializable  
{
private String routeId;
@NotNull(message = "RouteId cannot be empty ")
@XmlElement(name = "RouteId")
public String getRouteId() {
  return routeId;
 }
public void setRouteId(String routeId) {
 this.routeId = routeId;
  }
}`
```

Controller

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;    
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;   
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;   
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;   
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;   
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;   
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;   
import javax.validation.Valid;   
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j    
@RequestMapping(value = "/")    
public class MyControllerClass { 

@PostMapping(path = "/path/", consumes = MediaType. APPLICATION_XML_VALUE , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)    
public Mono\<List\<ResponseEntity\<ResponseModelData\>\>\> createPlanEvent( final @Valid  @RequestBody(required = true) Headmlw mlwRequest, BindingResult bindingResult)
{    
 `your text`//content goes here
 }    
}
```

Below **dependencies** are used

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>`
```

If I am using **import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody**;
it gives below error response, though I send xml data in requestbody

```
{     "type": "about:blank", 
      "title": "Bad Request", 
      "status": 400,  
      "detail": "Invalid request content."
  }
```

Comment: You have conflictual versions of jaxb in your pom.xml. You should remove jaxb_impl, and also remove versions for jakarta related artifacts (even glassfish jaxb runtime). Spring wil provide them.